# YouTube API 3 video fileDetails creationTime

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to get the creation time of a YouTube video in my account using the YouTube API 3. From the API docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), calling videos->list with the part "fileDetails" should return an element "creationTime":

> The date and time when the uploaded video file was created. The value is specified in ISO 8601 format.

I have uploaded a file to YouTube that I know from ffprobe has a "creation_time" tag:

```
"format": {
    "filename": "test.mp4",
    "nb_streams": 2,
    "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
    "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
    "start_time": "0.000000",
    "duration": "1.920000",
    "size": "1126058",
    "bit_rate": "4691908",
    "tags": {
        "major_brand": "isom",
        "minor_version": "0",
        "compatible_brands": "isom3gp4",
        "creation_time": "2013-06-12 11:08:34"
    }
}
```

which is presumably where YouTube would calculate their "creationTime" value...

However, the YouTube API fileDetails for this file shows:

```
fileDetails: {
    fileSize: "1126058",
    fileType: "video",
    container: "mov",
    videoStreams: [
        {
            widthPixels: 1280,
            heightPixels: 720,
            frameRateFps: 29.9167,
            aspectRatio: 1.7777777777778,
            codec: "h264",
            bitrateBps: "5946814",
            rotation: "clockwise"
        }
    ],
    audioStreams: [
        {
            channelCount: 2,
            codec: "aac",
            bitrateBps: "129487"
        }
    ],
    durationMs: "1438",
    bitrateBps: "6076301",
}
```

Should the creationTime element not be in the fileDetails part for this video? Do all videos not get this element?

FYI: I am using the php implementation of YouTube API 3 and I have authorized my page to access my account.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% guaranteed that file creation time will be available for all videos.

There is also a chance that you may be using older version of the [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

Try with [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) to see, if the API returns creation time for your videos.

Comment: I checked the API explorer and it also doesn't return the file creation time for this video. Do you know if there is a set of rules deciding whether the creation time is recorded / returned? Or a way to guarantee that it is returned? E.g. if the video has a meta tag "bla".